# Integration test - mock repository for Spring Controller

Tags: spring, rest, mockito, junit5, mockmvc

**LocationController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "location")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    private LocationService locationService;


    @GetMapping()
    public Page<LocationDTO> findLocations(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "5") Integer size){
            List<LocationDTO> locations = locationService.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
        return new PageImpl<>(locations);
    }

}
```

**LocationService.java**

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

@Service
public class LocationService {
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    public LocationService(LocationRepository locationRepository, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.locationRepository = locationRepository;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }


    public List<LocationDTO> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {

        return locationRepository.findAll(pageRequest)
                .stream()
                .map(location -> modelMapper.map(location, LocationDTO.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
   
}
```

**LocationDTO.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class LocationDTO  {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
}
```

**LocationRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Long> {
    public Location findByCode(String code);
}
```

**LocationControllerTest.java**

```
@WebMvcTest(LocationController.class)
public class LocationControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @MockBean
    private LocationService locationService;
    @MockBean
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Test
    void findLocationsTestRepository() throws Exception{
    Page<Location> pagedTasks = new PageImpl<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Location(1L,  "Sydney", "SYD"),
            new Location(2L,  "Singapore", "SIN"),
            new Location(3L, "Paris", "PAR")
    ));
        BDDMockito.given(locationRepository.findAll(any(PageRequest.class))).willReturn(pagedTasks);
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/location"));
        actions.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }

    @Test
    void findLocationsTestService() throws Exception{
        List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Location(1L,  "Sydney", "SYD"),
            new Location(2L,  "Singapore", "SIN"),
            new Location(3L, "Paris", "PAR")
         ));

        Stream<LocationDTO> locationsDTO = locations.stream().map(location -> modelMapper.map(location, LocationDTO.class));

        BDDMockito.given(locationService.findAll(any(PageRequest.class))).willReturn(locationsDTO.toList());
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/location"));
        actions.andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", hasSize(3)))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }
}
```

Test *findLocationsTestService()* works correct . I mocked LocationService.findAll on this test.

I have a problem with test *findLocationsTestRepository()*
As you can see i have a three layers Controller, Service and Repository.
I want to call Controller and mock Repository.

```
BDDMockito.given(locationRepository.findAll(any(PageRequest.class))).willReturn(pagedTasks);
```

Let's say integration test where front (Controller) and back (Repository).
I have output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1/location
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.global.cargotracker.interfaces.rest.LocationController
           Method = com.global.cargotracker.interfaces.rest.LocationController#findLocations(Integer, Integer)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"content":[],"pageable":"INSTANCE","last":true,"totalPages":1,"totalElements":0,"size":0,"number":0,"sort":{"empty":true,"sorted":false,"unsorted":true},"first":true,"numberOfElements":0,"empty":true}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

As you can see Body."content":[] list is empty.
Can you please tell me what i do wrong? Thanks.